# Change value in List<T> using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list where i whant to change the value of a double property in that list if that property has decimals.

If x.Value has decimals, I want to change that value to take just the first decimal woithout rounding it.

I'm trying this but can't get it right: 
(*Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement*)

```
var newList =
                correctionQoutas.ToList()
                .ForEach(x => x.Value%1 != 0 ? x.Value = Convert.ToDouble(string.Format("{0:0.0}", x)) : x.Value = x.Value);
```

EDIT:
correctionQoutas is a custom object that has four properties. Double StartTime, Double EndTime, Double Value and string Id.

Comment: Don't use `List.ForEach`(or even LINQ) if you want to change the content of a list or array. Instead loop it, for example with a `for`-loop. It's also more efficient, you don't need to create a new list as you do at `ToList()`.

Comment: What type is `correctionQoutas` (so that we know how to create new item of that type) ? And don't use `ToList().ForEach(...)`, use simple `Select(...).ToList()`. You create new list anyway.

Comment: In addition to Tim Schmelter's comment: `List<T>.ForEach()` does not return anything (it's return type is `void`). I think you're looking for `Select` instead, which would return a new enumeration.

Comment: No offense, but this seems like using Linq for the sole purpose of using linq, not because it's actually solving a problem (as a matter of fact, it's created a problem...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't modify a collection while you're iterating it.

Here's a simple approach

```
var list=correctionQoutas.ToList();

for(int i=0; i<list.Count(); i++)
   {
    if(list[i].Value % 1 != 0)
      { 
       list[i].Value = Convert.ToDouble(string.Format("{0:0.0}", list[i].Value)) ;
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to **transform the elements**, then you need to use the `Select()` LinQ function:

```
var newList =
            correctionQoutas.Select(x => x.Value%1 != 0 ? x.Value = Convert.ToDouble(string.Format("{0:0.0}", x)) : x.Value = x.Value);
```

This gives you an `IEnumerable`, to freeze the contents and actually do the evaluation, you can use the `ToList()` function after the `Select()` function.

If you simply need to get the **elements that are of a certain type**, you can do this:

```
var subList = correctionQoutas.OfType<MyQuota>();
```

That would give the subset that are `MyQuota` or are directly assignable to that type.  It's an easy way to filter out nulls.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I thought there is no _transform_ in Linq. `Select` is for _projection_, not _transformation_. And your `Select` returns an enumeration of `double`s (while having the side effect of changing the properties of the elements), I'm not sure that this is what OP wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to change the **properties of the elements in your enumeration**, you should not be using linq or `List<T>.ForEach` for that. (Your question does not sound like you want to copy the original objects). So simply iterate over that enumeration and set the new values:

```
foreach (var quota in correctionQoutas)
    quota.Value = (int)(quota.Value * 10) / 10d;
```

*Note* that I cut the trailing decimals by simple arithmetic instead of converting the values to strings and back.

Answer (score 0):

Without digging into what your actual conversion function is doing. To use a linq statement to get a new List of  `CorrectionQuota` you would do something like this:

```
var newList = correctionQoutas
   .Select(x => Convert(x))
   .ToList();

private  CorrectionQouta Convert(CorrectionQouta x){
    x.Value = x.Value % 1 != 0 ? 
        Convert.ToDouble(string.Format("{0:0.0}", x)) : x.Value);
    return x;
}
```

Transform the results into what you want first and then make the new List.

Answer (score 0):

Since you save your result to a new List anyway, you can just `Select` the result instead:

Oh and `%` wont do you any good here anyway, your number would be converted to `int` first, if it works at all.

The check if you have decimal places is unneccessary too, since the output will be a double anyway.

```
// depending on what correctionQuotas is, you might be able to omit ToList()
var newList = correctionQoutas.Select(x => Math.Truncate(10 * x.Value) / 10).ToList();
```